# Mozjpeg - Progressive jpeg image rendering showing a grayscale image first

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg-turbo, mozjpeg

I am using the following command to generate progressive JPEGs using mozjpeg (cjpeg utility)

```
cjpeg -quality 85 -outfile outputfile.jpg inputfile.jpg
```

On rendering this output image, a grayscale image is first shown which is then followed by a greenish image and then the original image. After quite a bit of study, i found that splitting of DC coefficients is done to reduce the size of image. But, i need the rendering to be a blurred to bright one. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option for this:

```
-dc-scan-opt   DC scan optimization mode
             - 0 One scan for all components
             - 1 One scan per component (default)
             - 2 Optimize between one scan for all components and one scan for 1st component
                 plus one scan for remaining components
```

The default causes grayscale look, because it sends luma separately from chroma.